# Returning only part of a list after a function call to save memory

Tags: functions, linear-algebra, output

I need to get only `V` of a singular value decomposition of a matrix. In MATLAB I could write:

```
A = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6]
[~, ~, V] = svd(A)
```

Is there a similar technique to ensure `U` and `S` are not saved in

```
A = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}
{U, S, V} = SingularValueDecomposition[A]
```

Comment: `V = Last@SingularValueDecomposition[A]`? I would also recommend not using single-letter upper case letters for your variable names because they may conflict with built in ones.

Comment: At the cost of additional computation time, you can save additional memory by using `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` (i.e., `V = SingularValueDecomposition[A][[-1]] // FullSimplify`)

Comment: @BobHanlon that's only if the symbolic form of the SVD is desired. In a memory-constrained environment I'm guessing the OP is using floating point matrices.